# JavaFX add new layout into parent layout

Tags: java, javafx

I have the following code which sets my parent layout:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/BaseStructure.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I want to add another layout to the `right` of the parent layout. How can I do this in the main class?

This is what my parent layout `.fxml` file looks like:

```
<VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="640.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Main">
   //more code here
   <right>
     //need my second layout here
   </right>
</VBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another layout of your choice that wraps two layouts you have:

```
HBox hbox = new HBox(10);
hbox.getChildren().addAll(getMySecondLayout(), root);
Scene scene = new Scene(hbox);
```

Alternatively you can redesign all GUI and use other layouts like `BorderPane`, `AnchorPane` etc.